# create new column with current timestamp in nano secods in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, unix-timestamp

I want to create a column in Hive table with current timestamp in nano seconds. how can i do that while inserting data.?

Answer (score 1):

the current `current_timestamp` functions in hive, does not give time in nano seconds.

But you can always [create your own functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins#HivePlugins-CreatingCustomUDFs) using hive UDF to handle the nano seconds timestamp.

Below is the example of UDF, which will return the `long` value of the nano time.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;

@UDFType(stateful = true)
public class NanoTimeUdf extends UDF{

    public long evaluate() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }

}
```

Create a Jar out of the above Java code(say tonanotime.jar) and add the jar to create the udf function to return current nano time.

```
ADD JAR /home/amit/tonanotime.jar;
create TEMPORARY FUNCTION toNanoTime AS 'NanoTimeUdf';
```

Now, the `toNanoTime` function is available, you  can use in select query to insert into the new table like:
e.g

```
insert into table select toNanoTime() from other_table;
```